Гиперссылки в коде
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Visual Studio Code убрать гиперссылки в коде.


Что вы имеете ввиду?


Зажмите CTRL + SHIFT + P
Выберите Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)
Добавьте туда следующее

    {
        "editor.links": false,
        "editor.hover.enabled": false
    }

Не забудьте запятую перед или после, в зависимости от того куда внесли данные измененияне забудь CTRL + S чтобы применить изменения.
Зажмите CTRL + S и закройте settings.json.
После данного действия у вас не будут работать гиперссылки.

[![Изменения][2]][2]
"editor.links": false - Отключит гиперссылку, подчеркивание и переход при зажатой клавише CTRL.
"editor.hover.enabled": false - в случае если необходимо отключить подсказки при наведении мыши к url ссылке не будет показывать подсказку о необходимости зажатия CTRL ЛКМ по ссылке, но будет работать при зажатом CTRL и ЛКМ и будет подчеркнуто, так и отключит остальные подсказки выдаваемым при наведении курсора мыши.

Минус не мой, но зачем вторая строка? Она же даже серым цветом выделена, нет такой настройки.

Да там должно быть "editor.hover.enabled": false, т.к. кому-то удобнее просто не видеть всплывающую подсказку при наведении курсора на различные функции, url ссылки и т.д.
